# Unable to see render when I use the .exe

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, game-development, directx-11

I have been trying to get this to work but I am at a loss as to why its not displaying the red dot, this is a test before I replace the dot with an actual gui. any help would be appreciated.

I have checked to make sure the libs are there and all correct as well as the .h files, I build and then try to click the exe and nothing shows up. I know that I am missing something here, not all my code by the way but any help would be appreciated. I have followed a TY tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aY8MNCNN-cY&t=1638s

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <dwmapi.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <imgui.h>
#include <imgui_impl_dx11.h>
#include <imgui_impl_win32.h>

extern IMGUI_IMPL_API LRESULT ImGui_ImplWin32_WndProcHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

LRESULT CALLBACK window_procedure(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param) {
    if (ImGui_ImplWin32_WndProcHandler(window, message, w_param, l_param)) {
        return 0L;
    }

    if (message == WM_DESTROY) {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0L;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(window, message, w_param, l_param);

}

INT APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE instance, HINSTANCE, PSTR, INT cmd_show) {
    WNDCLASSEXW wc{};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = window_procedure;
    wc.hInstance = instance;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"External Overlay Class";

    RegisterClassExW(&wc);

    const HWND window = CreateWindowExW(
        WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED,
        wc.lpszClassName,
        L"Overlay",
        NULL,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        1920,
        1080,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        wc.hInstance,
        nullptr
    );

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(window, RGB(255, 0, 0), BYTE(255), LWA_ALPHA);

    
    
  {

      RECT client_area{};
      GetClientRect(window, &client_area);

      RECT window_area{};
      GetWindowRect(window, &window_area);

      POINT diff{};
      ClientToScreen(window, &diff);

     const MARGINS margins{
         window_area.left + (diff.x - window_area.left),
         window_area.top + (diff.y - window_area.top),
         client_area.right,
         client_area.bottom
     };

    DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(window, &margins);

  }

  DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd{};
  sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60U;
  sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1U;
  sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
  sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1U;
  sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
  sd.BufferCount = 2U;
  sd.OutputWindow = window;
  sd.Windowed = TRUE;
  sd.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
  sd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;

  constexpr D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL levels[2]{
      D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
      D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0
  };

  ID3D11Device* device{ nullptr };
  ID3D11DeviceContext* device_context{ nullptr };
  IDXGISwapChain* swap_chain{ nullptr };
  ID3D11RenderTargetView* render_target_view{ nullptr };
  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL level{};

  D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
      nullptr,
      D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
      nullptr,
      0U,
      levels,
      2U,
      D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
      &sd,
      &swap_chain,
      &device,
      &level,
      &device_context
  );

  ID3D11Texture2D* back_buffer{ nullptr };
  swap_chain->GetBuffer(0U, IID_PPV_ARGS(&back_buffer));

  if (back_buffer) {
      device->CreateRenderTargetView(back_buffer, nullptr, &render_target_view);
      back_buffer->Release();
  }
  else {
      return 1;
  }

  ShowWindow(window, cmd_show);
  UpdateWindow(window);

  ImGui::CreateContext();
  ImGui::StyleColorsDark();

  ImGui_ImplWin32_Init(window);
  ImGui_ImplDX11_Init(device, device_context);

  bool running = true;

  while (running) {
      MSG msg;
      while (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE)) {
          TranslateMessage(&msg);
          DispatchMessage(&msg);

          if (msg.message = WM_QUIT) {
              running = false;
          }
      }

      if (!running) {
          break;
      }

      ImGui_ImplDX11_NewFrame();
      ImGui_ImplWin32_NewFrame();

      ImGui::NewFrame();

      ImGui::GetBackgroundDrawList()->AddCircleFilled({500, 500}, 20.f, ImColor (1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.5f));

      // rendering

      ImGui::Render();

      constexpr float color[4]{0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f};
      device_context->OMSetRenderTargets(1U, &render_target_view, nullptr);
      device_context->ClearRenderTargetView(render_target_view, color);

      ImGui_ImplDX11_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());

      swap_chain->Present(0U, 0U);

  }


  ImGui_ImplDX11_Shutdown();
  ImGui_ImplWin32_Shutdown();

  ImGui::DestroyContext();

  if (swap_chain) {
      swap_chain->Release();
  }
  if (device_context) {
      device_context->Release();
  }
  if (device) {
      device->Release();
  }

  if (render_target_view) {
      render_target_view->Release();
  }

  DestroyWindow(window);
  UnregisterClassW(wc.lpszClassName, wc.hInstance);


  return 0;
}

written in visual studio cpp
```

Comment: Since you're using Visual Studio, you can run the program in the built-in debugger to start narrowing down the problem. Add code to check the return value from all functions that provide one. Set a breakpoint at the start of `main` and start stepping through one line at a time. Something, somewhere, will be returning an error, or you might be missing a step or providing incorrect data.

Comment: Can you post the compilable project somewhere?

Comment: @SimonMourier I can link it on my GitHub I am relatively new to CS and programming so if there is something else needed please let me know I greatly appreciate the help and I love the stackoverflow community! https://github.com/Warenfor/Gameystuff

Comment: @paddy I added the project on Github, when I compile it shows me no errors, when I run the .exe it shows no errors either that I can see.

Comment: You misinterpreted what I said. Debugging doesn't "show" errors. You need to _examine_ the program state, including possible error codes returned from functions that might provide information about an operation you assumed succeeded but didn't. You also should check all relevant variable values are what you expect. If you get lost, then strip your program down to the absolute minimal that works. Try to just create a non-transparent window and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by this:

```
MSG msg;
while (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE)) {
  TranslateMessage(&msg);
  DispatchMessage(&msg);

  if (msg.message = WM_QUIT) { // assignment !!!
    running = false;
  }
}
```

So, you're just quitting as soon as you've started. Change it to

```
msg.message == WM_QUIT
```

and it works.

Additional notes:

Your current warning level is 3, you can get to level 4:

[image]

And visual studio will tell you this:

```
1>E:\kilroywashere\Gameystuff\IESP\src\main.cpp(142):
    warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression
```

Also you should check for *all* errors for all Windows API and DirectX calls (HRESULTs).

Comment: Thank you for that! I knew it was something simple that I had missed, I am only in the first year of my degree program and Stackoverflow and its community teaches me more than school does...